# Selenium C# - Run multiple tests from same test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

So I have a suite of tests that all can be run individually and I have set an excel sheet, will move it to a db later though it shouldn't matter for this, that contains a list of tests with browsers and days that I want to run them. Each days test will be run on my server through one test category that contains the ability to call multiple different tests with different parameters.

This is all working, but I am looking for a better way to kick off each of these tests so that I still have the individual tests results the same way I get from either running them individually or in a build that contains a category of tests. This is also to ensure that the tests are running executing independently.

So the question is how can this be achieved.

Comment: Are you using NUnit and what you mean by result the same way as individual or a test suite? Are you using any other tool for reporting?

Comment: @Chan1385 I am using MSTest. it is reporting the individual tests in the one log as opposed to multiple log files. No other reporting tool is being used.

Comment: @DoctorWizard-In NUnit, we have annotations TestBreakdown, TestFixtureBreakdown where we can handle this. if I have got your requirement correctly, you need reporting of each test of suite in individual log file.